# How can I make a water wake effect?

Tags: fluid-simulation, dynamic-paint, ocean-simulation

I wish to create the illusion of an object that is stationary to  be moving along a surface.

I have a sphere and a plane, and the desired outcome would be for a water "wake" effect to be behind the sphere.

the sphere is to be stationary.

here is an image of what i would like to acheive, though this image is using dynamic paint and me dragging the ball across the surface.
[image]

Is this possible?

The user out come is a wave I am creating.
https://i.imgur.com/waLSK5I.jpg
I am going to have a surf board on the wave.

I am looking alot into gemetry nodes now that the simulation node has arrived.

this is inspiring
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITWq5sEPYbs

Thankyou in adance for all your input

Comment: I would think so, weight paint and instance some particles with initial velocity

Comment: @AllenSimpson But particles shooting out behind the sphere would look like something swimming away from the sphere, not as if the sphere was moving forward... if I got you wrong and you could elaborate further on your idea this would be great, since I would like to know a solution for this problem, too.

Comment: DP does work, if you move the water, not the ball.. could you rig a curve-deformed conveyor-belt of water? I'll try it, when I can, if you don't get there first.

Comment: thankyou for all responses. I can update my question with more information to give you a better understanding of what i have tried and what I intend to use the effect for. I will update in a few hours after work

Comment: @RobinBetts I've tried the conveyor belt method, but the waves on the moving canvas are not working in the same way as if the brush was moving: ["static" wave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAHNu.gif)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann strange, [I seem to be doing OK](https://imgur.com/a/jWU0idE). Apart from the weld in the belt.

Comment: @RobinBetts Perhaps you can give this as an answer because to me it looks like it's providing a solution for the question. Maybe it's just my settings. I used the same canvas and brush settings on the conveyor version as on the moving sphere, but somehow it looks different...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a conveyor-belt of water.

- Set up a subdivided plane-strip of water
- *Curve* deform it along a loop with a flat top and bottom
- Adjust the length of the belt to close the loop, and assign a Weld modifier to stitch it up
- Animate the belt along its deformation axis, as far as you like.

Here are the settings for the example file attached, at my scale, for the brush and canvas:

[image]

The result is a little large for a BSE .gif, but can be found [here](https://imgur.com/a/jWU0idE)

There are a couple of hitches to iron out, I think. The weld doesn't seem to play well with the simulation, when first encountered, but seems to settle down. The wake travels all the way round the belt.. if you needed a perfectly smooth surface ahead of the ball for a very long shot, that would require some thought.

[image]

Comment: wow this looks good. It certainly answers the question. I will give a plus 1 as its on the right track and has demonstrated a possible solution. I am still looking at other ways.

Comment: @ben For sure. Fair enough. It's not perfect.

Comment: I might have an answer with geometry nodes . If it does not work and its been a week fro this post I will set the answer to be Robins

Comment: There was a geometry nodes solution however its made by someone else and they are selling it as a product.

Comment: Hi, @ben, I wonder, are they doing the whole simulation? A spring-force and damp  on edge-length would do it ... That seems a bit re-inventing the wheel..